# Default not showing because of nil method when paperclip photo not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attachable, :polymorphic => true, :counter_cache => true

  has_attached_file :data,
    :styles => {
      :ppc_full => "500x375>", 
      :ppc_preview => "250x250", 
      :ppc_thumb => "76x76#",
      :default_url => "shop/:style.jpg"
    }
end

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photos, :as => :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

When I do this, I hope to return the default photo when there is no photo associated:

```
image_tag(@shop.photos.last.data.url(:ppc_preview))
```

but instead it gives me this error:

```
undefined method `data' for nil:NilClass
```

I have others working fine, but not this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this problem with a view helper:

```
def show_img_for shop
  unless shop.images.blank?
    image_tag(shop.photos.last.data.url(:ppc_preview))
  else
    image_tag('/path/to/default/img.png', :alt => 'derp')
  end
end
```

Impliment that in app/helpers/shop_helper.rb and then call it in your view passing in the shop and it should do the trick. You could also tack it on as a model function but since its really a view related problem a helper is likely the most appropriate solution.